# Mat-checkbox [checked]="false" does not work angular 6

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

My mat-checkbox does not change value when using the `checked` input property.

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="false"
              formControlName="value1">Value1
</mat-checkbox>
```

- Please explain the usage of the `checked` input property ie: what are the different methods for passing a boolean variable to the
  `checked` Input property?
- Are there ways to default selection using `FormControl`
  without needing to use the `checked` input property on the component?

Comment: take your original code, and remove the `[checked]` field. The checkbox should default to true/false depending on what `value1` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `checked` property is a boolean input that expects `true` or `false`

> @Input()
>   checked: boolean

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api

Using `[checked]="true"` would result in a checked box, `[checked]="false"` would result in unchecked box.

---

The following would be how to check with `FormControl`

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="checkboxFormControl">Checked Using FormControl</mat-checkbox>

checkboxFormControl = new FormControl(true);
```

---

Following would be checked using `FormControl` inside of `FormGroup`

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-checkbox formControlName="checked">Checked Using formControlName in FormGroup</mat-checkbox>
</form>

  myForm = new FormGroup({
    checked: new FormControl(true)
  })
```

---

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tylt6w?embed=1&file=app/checkbox-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

I think this code help you
 html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
          <mat-checkbox id="Value1" class="Value1" color="primary"
                        formControlName="Value1">Value1</mat-checkbox>
        </form>
        <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>
```

ts:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
         Value1: [false],
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still does not work

Comment: @tcw9721 can tell me what happen or error is occur?. because this code is working properly on system.

Comment: I get the alert

  `It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
    Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.
    
    For more information on this, see our API docs here:`

Comment: @tcw9721 if you are using ngModel on check box please remove that because reactive form and template driven two different approach in angular both rule are different. i'm share with you link that is working please check [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtdnfo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

use two way binding:

```
<mat-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="checked">{{checked}}</mat-checkbox>
```

now in your component.ts 'checked' has the value of checkbox